# How to install driver for Huion hs610 graphic tablet

Tags: drivers, apt, package-management, kernel, dpkg

I recently purchased a Huion Hs610 Graphic tablet, and when I try to install the driver it shows the following error:

```
(Reading database ... 336798 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack digimend-dkms_10_all.deb ...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 10
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.

Unpacking digimend-dkms (10) over (10) ...

Setting up digimend-dkms (10) ...

Loading new digimend-10 DKMS files...

Building for 5.11.0-25-generic

Building initial module for 5.11.0-25-generic

Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.11.0-25-generic (x86_64)

Consult /var/lib/dkms/digimend/10/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package digimend-dkms (--install):

 installed digimend-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10

Errors were encountered while processing:
 digimend-dkms
```

make.log file details

```
DKMS make.log for digimend-10 for kernel 5.11.0-25-generic (x86_64)
Tue Aug 10 12:53:16 AM IST 2021
make -C /lib/modules/5.11.0-25-generic/build SUBDIRS=/var/lib/dkms/digimend/10/build modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.11.0-25-generic'
  SYNC    include/config/auto.conf.cmd
  LEX     scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.c
/bin/sh: 1: flex: not found
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.host:9: scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.c] Error 127
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  YACC    scripts/kconfig/parser.tab.[ch]
/bin/sh: 1: bison: not found
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.host:17: scripts/kconfig/parser.tab.h] Error 127
make[2]: *** [Makefile:629: syncconfig] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:737: include/config/auto.conf.cmd] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.11.0-25-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:22: modules] Error 2
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Could you update your question with the contents of `/var/lib/dkms/digimend/10/build/make.log` as listed in the output? This might be useful in determing where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure you have the `build-essential` package and the correct headers for your kernel are installed, before trying to install that package again?

Try these commands to install those packages.

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: Now got this error

`code`
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.11.0-25-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/digimend/10/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package digimend-dkms (--configure):
 installed digimend-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned er
ror exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 digimend-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
`code`

Comment: If the `make.log` is same as the one you’ve posted to the question, you need to install the `flex` and `bison` packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the HS610 driver from Huion [on this page](https://www.huion.com/index.php?m=content&c=index&a=lists&catid=16&myform=1&down_title=HS610).

Scroll down to the bottom of the page and click to download the newest "deb" file version listed.

[image]

**Next**, run the following command to create a working directory:

```
mkdir ~/HUION
```

**Then**, move or copy the downloaded file to the `~/HUION` directory.

**Finally**, run the following commands to install the driver:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install ~/HUION/*.deb
```